# Area Learning save issue with new Tango LucidaAnseris version SDK for Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I haven't been able to save and ADF since updating to the latest SDK of project tango for Unity. On Monday I had Area Description and Area Learning working perfectly, yesterday I updated to the latest SDK and since then I haven't been able to save ADF's. Thinking that it could be a problem specific to my project I created a new empty project, imported Tango's SKD and builded the area learning example scene to find that is having the same issue. 
Is anyone in the same situation as me and if so, is there a solution apart from reverting back to the past SDK?

Edit:

Just to add a bit more information, after recording an ADF and pressing save a error appears that states "Could not save  area description" and the error type is -2 or TANGO_INVALID, the comment on the code is "General invalid state"

Answer (score 0):

The same happens to me. SaveMetadata and GetMetadata functions don't work properly in my case. I only can save ADF file without modifying the metadata.

I'm trying now with the new Mira version and it happens again...

EDITED: Everything fixed with the last Tango Core update and Mira release. Metadata get and save work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I had to revert to the previous version of the SDK while waiting for a fix. Thank you for letting me know. (Should I set it as solved or this does not constitute as a solution?)